# Why do sometimes my Flask-Login python app logged out users in just under one minute?

Tags: python, flask-login

It occur randomly though, when I am about to access a restricted page. It'll get directed to login page. It never occurred in localhost, but often occurred in stagging servers (without valid SSH certificate) and seldom occurred in production server (with valid SSH certificate)

Any suggestion why this behaviour happened?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what settings your cookie duration is set to.
https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cookie-settings

REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION should default to 365 days but you should try to reset it and see.